# Scrapy CrawlSpider - errback for start_urls

Tags: scrapy

I'm using `CrawlSpider` with rule linkextractor that has `errback`.

I'm using `parse_start_url` to be able to parse the `start_urls` but I need `errback` for them also.

```
class CS(CrawlSpider):
    name = "CS"
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[], deny=[]), follow=True, callback='my_parse', errback='my_errback'),)           
    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 3,
        #etc
    }
    
    start_urls = ['url']
    allowed_domains = ['domain']
    
    def my_errback(self, failure):
        # log all failures
    
    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return self.my_parse(response)

    def my_parse(self, response):
        # parse responses
```

The issue I'm facing is that the errback is called ONLY for the links extracted and NOT the start_urls.

I cannot use start_requests method (as per below) since I'm using CrawlSpider and rules. When I do, only the start_urls are scraped:

```
def start_requests(self):
            for u in self.start_urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(u, callback=self.my_parse,
                                        errback=self.my_errback)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34345668/13903397

Basically, we have to use `start_requests` but remove the callback parameter. That way the default self.parse will be called and rules are going to be respected.

```
class CS(CrawlSpider):
    name = "CS"
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[], deny=[]), follow=True, callback='my_parse', errback='my_errback'),)           
    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 3,
        #etc
    }
    
    start_urls = ['url']
    allowed_domains = ['domain']

    def start_requests(self):
        for u in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(u, errback=self.my_errback)
    
    def my_errback(self, failure):
        # log all failures
    
    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return self.my_parse(response)

    def my_parse(self, response):
        # parse responses
```